# Show that $\int_0^1\sqrt{1+x^4}dx\geq \frac{\sqrt{10}}{3}.$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, inequality

Show that $$\int_0^1\sqrt{1+x^4}dx\geq \frac{\sqrt{10}}{3}.$$
Actually, I am trying to make Cauchy-Schwarz work for it, but it doesn't work. Could someone give some idea to fix it?

Comment: Do you know power series of $f(x)=\sqrt{1+x}$ ?

Comment: Is it work for it?

Comment: It will (eventually) work, as long as you take enough terms.

Comment: If you tried to use C-S, show us your work so we can help determine any errors.  Claiming you "are trying" without showing any display of your efforts amounts to not helping us to help you.  Afterall, would it be helpful to you if I answered "Ah, yes, I tried something, and it worked", and told you nothing else?  You need to aid us and display some investment in your work;  this site is not a "do my work for me" service."

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax and see [MathJax tutorial](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189). Please [don't use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to those who use screen readers. Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for information on writing a good question. People will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include an explanation of your own attempts.

Answer (score 3):

(Fill in the gaps as needed. If you're stuck, show your work.)

From the expansion of $ \sqrt{ 1 + x^4}$ or otherwise, conclude that for $0 \leq x \leq 1,$

$$ \sqrt{ 1 + x^4 } \geq 1 + \frac{x^4}{2} - \frac{x^8}{8}. \quad \quad (1)$$

Hence, show that

$$ \int_0^1 \sqrt{ 1+x^4} \, dx \geq \int_0^1 1 + \frac{x^4}{2} - \frac{x^8}{8} \, dx = \frac{391}{360} > \frac{ \sqrt{10} } { 3} . $$

---

Notes

- In fact, inequality $(1)$ holds for all $x$. This can be shown by
  A) RHS is negative when $ x^4 \geq 8$ and
  B) Squaring both sides to show it's true for $ x^4 < 8$.

Comment: Can you please explain how can we "expand" $\sqrt{1+x^4}$ ? Are you talking about a  Taylor Series Expansion ?

Comment: @Kolmogorov Yes (as suggested by the comment on the question). The idea that $ \sqrt{ 1 + x } \geq 1 + x/2 - x^2 / 8 $ is very useful. Taylor series expansion gives us an almost immediate conclusion due to the alternating series with coefficients of smaller values. Of course, there are other inequalities that we could have used for this problem.